# Someone just upvoted a whole bunch of my answers (too many to be accidental) - Does this happen often?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit, serial-voting

I have answered a few questions tonight and I assume that someone who thought my answer was helpful seems to have upvoted a bunch of my answers. While it is of course pleasant to see rep ticking over, I think I would prefer to get it the *honorable* way - through elbow grease so to speak.

I have searched a good few questions on Meta:

[Discouraging Down (or Up) Voting "Sprees" (Rapid Voting)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61545/discouraging-down-or-up-voting-sprees-rapid-voting?rq=1)

[What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)

and quite a few more from the similar/suggested questions when writing this, but I am curious, I have heard that too many downvotes from a single user trips up a filter and the rep is returned - is this also the case when someone upvotes a whole heap in a short timeframe?

I picked up a bronze badge (which I know won't get taken away, just the next one won't count) if there is a rollback - but if there is a rollback, when does it kick in - will this do-gooder actually spoil my chances of hitting the rep cap tonight?

Comment: Yes. If you receive too many up-votes at once then these will be revoked and the reputation removed.

Comment: @ChrisF Would you know if this is a "once per day" thing or should I expect to see it change in an hour or so?

Comment: It's once a day (the same as serial down-votes - as it's the same scrpt) as far as I know.

Comment: @ChrisF Much appreciated. If you pop that into an answer, I can accept and this will drop off the activity list, otherwise it will stay open for two days until I can accept a self posted answer sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you receive too many up-votes at once then these will be revoked and the reputation removed.

It happens once a day (the same as serial down-votes - as it's the same script) as far as I know.